# Are Chase credit cards commonly accepted for purchases?

Tags: canada, credit-card

While trying to buy stuff online with a credit card, the options available are usually restricted to Visa, MasterCard and AMEX. I am thinking of getting a credit card from [Chase](https://applynow.chase.com/FlexAppWeb/renderApp.do?SPID=FBH6&CELL=6H8X&AFFID=pngc6t7Ewoo-qMA3mNRFnS2M.XEmspA4NA&pvid=F526041987&jp_cmp=cc/307156/aff/3-10002206/na), but where could I actually use it? I am in Toronto, Canada, and I don't remember seeing any restaurant or grocery store that accepts Chase cards.

Comment: Chase cards are usually participants in the Mastercard or Visa networks and can be used wherever the appropriate type of card is accepted.  Check the logo on the Chase card to see whether it is usable on the Mastercard network or the Visa network.

Comment: I don't recall seeing anywhere that accepts AMEX, either, though I have at least heard of them, unlike Chase. The market here in Ireland (and I think in Europe as a whole) is entirely sewn up by Visa and MasterCard.

Comment: It's restricted, I think, because the Discover network charges a larger fee to accept their cards. All other banks partner with another network.

Comment: @TRiG, Chase is a bank (JPMorgan Chase Bank, N.A.) and a subsidiary of JPMorgan Chase & Co., but it is not a credit card company. It's a US-based company, so I'm not entirely surprised you haven't heard of it in Ireland, but apparently JPMorgan Europe, Ltd. has a large presence in the UK; perhaps you've heard of them?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you read the fine print in the Pricing & Terms section of that card, you'll see:

> By becoming a Visa Business Card cardmember, you agree that the card is being used only for business purposes and that the card is being issued to a public or private company including a sole proprietor or employees or contractors of an organization.

So that card is a Chase-branded Visa card, and should be accepted anywhere other Visa cards are.

Credit cards are normally either MasterCard or Visa, although many of them make that rather inconspicuous.  The only major exceptions I know of are American Express and Discover.  (And store cards that are only good at one particular store.)

Comment: It should be noted that some store branded cards can be used anywhere (such as my Amazon and Ebay credit cards).

Comment: @pacoverflow, I expect those cards are either MasterCard or Visa.  I was listing credit cards that are neither.  I don't know of any store-branded card accepted outside its own store which is neither MasterCard nor Visa.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, most credit cards are backed by some bank or another (Chase, Bank of America, Citibank, RBS, Barclays, etc.) This is independent of which processing network the card uses (Visa, MasterCard, etc.) Discover, however, is its own bank.